# Why is half of mesh transparent in edit mode?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, eevee-render-engine

So this mesh (downloaded) looks like this in object mode -

[image]

Then in edit mode looks like only some of the faces actually exist-

[image]

There's no modifiers on the object. What is this?

Comment: move the mirror modifier on the top

Comment: @atek what do you mean? It doesn't have mirror modifier, and it doesn't need to be mirrored exactly. Something is weird in edit mode

Comment: could you please share just this part?

Comment: `Alt+H` to unhide faces maybe?

Comment: move the order of the mirror modifier on the top and rest or play with the modifier order

Comment: @atek dude there is no mirror modifier

Comment: @Merlin that was it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Parts of the mesh are hidden.

You can unhide the using either:

`Alt + H` hotkey

Or from the menu in edit mode:

`Mesh -> Show/Hide -> Reveal Hidden`